# Como alterar o nome do arquivo baixado utilizando selenium + chromedrive?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome, pdf

Eu tenho um script que usa o Selenium Python para baixar uma página em PDF [feito com base nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56897041/how-to-save-opened-page-as-pdf-in-selenium-python)

Meu objetivo no momento é mudar o nome desse arquivo para que fique localizado com o nome que escolhi e depois mudar a pasta de destino do arquivo salvo.

Minhas dúvidas são:
Onde devo alterar para que o arquivo seja salvo com o nome que eu escolher?

Mesmo com as alterações feitas na variável "prefs=", o arquivo continua sendo salvo no diretório padrão do chrome.

No momento tenho o seguinte código:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') # Escondendo o navegador
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
settings = {
    "recentDestinations": [{
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": "",
        }],
        "isLandscapeEnabled": True,
        "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
        "version": 2,
    }

prefs = {
    "printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState": json.dumps(settings),
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups" : 0,

    "download.name":"name_file", # ?????? ESTE CÓDIGO NÃO ALTERA O NOME

    "download.default_directory": r'C:\Users\diretorio_escolhido\\' # ESTE CÓDIGO NÃO ALTERA O DESTINO,

    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
}


chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(name_Object.url)
sleep(5) # Pausa para carregar os dados
driver.execute_script('window.print();')

print('Gerou o PDF')
```

Comment: Não sei se pode ser isso, mas eu tenho um código em que eu passo o default_directory como variável e ele aceita. Tenta declarar esse caminho como variável, talvez funcione. tipo caminho = r'C:\Users\diretorio_escolhido\\' e depois "download.default_directory": caminho .

Answer (score -4):

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Para alterar o local de salvamento, mude download.default_directorypara savefile.default_directorypara que seu local de salvamento funcione.

Infelizmente, acho que não podemos alterar o nome do arquivo antes do download, mas você pode renomear seu arquivo após o download , renomeando o arquivo mais recente na pasta de download:

```
import os    
import shutil
download_folder = "C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\Test"
filename = max([download_folder + "\\" + f for f in os.listdir(Initial_path)],key=os.path.getctime)
shutil.move(filename,os.path.join(Initial_path,r"newPDFName.pdf"))
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).